# Integrating when power is -1

Tags: integration, functions

I'm studying acceleration as a function of velocity and displacement as part of my mechanics module, but I'm not sure how to integrate this acceleration expression.

If you had a situation were $a = \frac{1}{s + 2}$ and you wanted to find $s$ when $v$ is equal to a certain value, you would have to integrate the above equation like $\int v dv = \int \frac{1}{s + 2} ds$, or as far as I understand anyway.  But if you bring $s + 2$ to negative index form you get $s^{-1} + 2^{-1}$, and if you were to integrate that expression you would get powers of $0$ and it would not work.  Obviously I'm doing it wrong, but that is my thought process.

Comment: $\frac{1}{s + 2}\neq s^{-1} + 2^{-1}$ Think about $\frac 1x$ where $x=s+2$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int x^{-1}=\log(x)+C$$
Also remember that $$\frac{1}{s+2} \not= s^{-1}+2^{-1}$$

Let me know if that didn't answer your question.

Comment: Ok, so I put the log in so it became $v^2 = 2log(s + 2) + 2C$.  If you're told that when $v = 0, s = 0$, then to find C I did $0^2 = 2log(2) + 2C$ and punched it into the calculator to get -0.301..., which seems like a strange number to get.  Have I done something wrong?

Comment: @TiernanWatson When you integrate $a=\frac{dv}{dt}$ you just get $v$, not $\frac{1}{2}v^2$.

Comment: That's slightly confusing me then, because in the book examples they take $a = v \frac{dv}{ds}$  and they get $\frac{v^2}{2}$

Comment: @TiernanWatson Huh, well that is confusing to me as well - in fact, it looks plain wrong (if $a$ is the acceleration, $v$ is the velocity and $s$ is the place)! The acceleration is *defined* as the derivative of the velocity w.r.t time.

Comment: The book says the relationship is obtained by $a = \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{ds} * \frac{ds}{dt} = \frac{dv}{ds} * v$ if that makes sense to you?

Comment: @TiernanWatson Assuming the $x$'s were meant as $\times$ (the code for it is \times), then yes, that does make sense. But if you integrate that expression w.r.t time, you still don't get $\frac{1}{2}v^2$!

Comment: @TiernanWatson I had actually misread the integral on the RHS; I hadn't seen it was w.r.t $s$. Look at Deepak's answer, I believe what he writes is correct!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to gain a deeper understanding of what's going on here.

First of all, what you wrote: $\displaystyle \int vdv = \int \frac{1}{s+2}ds$ is, in fact, correct (some others seem confused by this).

To see why, consider $\displaystyle I = \int a ds$. Put $\displaystyle a = \frac{dv}{dt}$, to give $\displaystyle I = \int \frac{dv}{dt} ds$. Rearrange to give: $\displaystyle I = \int \frac{ds}{dt} dv$. Finally, use $\displaystyle v = \frac{ds}{dt}$ to get $\displaystyle I = \int vdv$. Hence $\displaystyle \int a ds = \int v dv$, and this can be used in the derivation of the kinetic energy formula, for instance.

Next, you seem to have some confusion about how to compute $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{s+2} ds$. First off, note that in general, $\displaystyle \frac{1}{a + b} \neq a^{-1} + b^{-1}$. So you can't split up the denominator that way.

Instead, try the substitution $\displaystyle x = s+2$. This gives $\displaystyle ds = dx$ and the integral becomes $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{x} dx = \ln x + c = \ln (s+2) + c$ ($\displaystyle c$ is an arbitrary constant that you can avoid by employing definite integrals with the appropriate bounds, a method often preferred when dealing with physical problems).

Comment: Just got it. But my question is, when you integrate $\int v dv$, why do you not put a $+ C$ with it?

Comment: @TiemanWatson The constant is implicit and is omitted since you're equating two indefinite integrals ($\int v dv = \int a ds$). When you're actually writing down the expression the LHS evaluates to, you should include a constant, i.e. ($\frac 12 v^2 + c$). Then use the physical parameters relevant to the scenario to work out that constant. In practicenit is better to use definite integrals with a specified lower bound to do this, e.g. When $s=0,v=0$, so $\int_0^V v dv = \int_0^S a ds$, and that avoids the constants.